# Vertical alignment almost working

Tags: css

Can anyone see why the following does not quite work.  The image is vertically centered within 'VCentInner' correctly but the following Title text seems to align with the image top rather than being vertically within VCentInner.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style>
            * {
    margin: 0;
    }
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    }
    #container {
    min-height: 100%;
    }

    #header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 10em;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    }
    .VCentOuter {
    top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; display: table;
    background-color: green;
    }
    #headinner{
    height: 8em;
    background-color: yellow;
    }
    .VCentInner {
    display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: pink;
    }

    #header img {
    float: left;
    <!--height: 2em;-->
    background-color: yellow;
    }
    #title{
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    }
    #clearheader{
    height: 10em;
    }


    .centered{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
    .txtcenter{
    text-align: center;
    }   

    #content{
    border: 1px red dotted;
    }

    #menu {
        position: absolute;
        bottom : 0px;
        width:100%;
        height: 2em;
        background: cyan;
        overflow:hidden;
    }


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="clearheader"></div>
            <div id="content">
                Content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="header">
            <div class="VCentOuter" id="headinner">
                <div class="VCentInner" id="title">
                    <img src="images/burgee2.gif"/>
                    Title text
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                Menu goes here - tab1 - tab2 - tab3 - tab4 - tab5 - tab6 - tab7 - tab8 - tab9 - tab10 - tab11 - tab12
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firstly, `<!--height: 2em;-->` is not how you comment in CSS. Use `/*height: 2em;*/` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless that image needs to be a link (or otherwise an actual element), the easiest solution is probably to make it into a CSS `background-image`:

```
<div class="VCentInner" id="title">
    Title text
</div>
```

With extra CSS:

```
#title {
    background: url(http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff) left center no-repeat
}
```

If it does need to be an element:

```
<div class="VCentOuter" id="headinner">
    <div class="VCentInner" style="width: 100px">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class="VCentInner" id="title">
        Title text
    </div>
</div>
```